# Get exclusive lock constant? In ctypes it is O_EXLOCK

Tags: files, javascript

I'm trying to open a file with exclusive lock via Javscript. So the library to open is no sweat just the number to pass as unixFlags is a problem.

This is syntax:

```
OS.File.open('/path/to/file', {unixFlags: NUMBER_HERE});
```

Does anyone know the number to put in NUMBER_HERE which is falg for exclusive lock?

Thanks

Comment: This appears to be off-topic because it is a question about Javascript.

Comment: (But for the record, the answer is probably 32, as you could have figured out by `printf`ing the value of `O_EXLOCK` in a C program.)

Comment: Oh I just gave syntax, it actually is use ctypes and tapping into linux api, so whatever flags you guys use to get exclusive lock is same

Comment: @fkraiem thanks for that, how can I express that as `0o4777` it wont accept 32. :(

Answer (score 2):

I think it maybe `OS.Constants.libc.O_EXLOCK`. From the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript_OS.Constants#Unix_opening_mode):

```
O_EXLOCK    Atomically obtain an exclusive lock.
```

There's also an [example code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript_OS.File/OS.File_for_the_main_thread#Example_of_opening_file_and_keeping_it_locked) which suggests this is the value:

```
let options = {
  winShare: 0 // Exclusive lock on Windows
};
if (OS.Constants.libc.O_EXLOCK) {
  // Exclusive lock on *nix
  options.unixFlags = OS.Constants.libc.O_EXLOCK;
}
let file = yield OS.File.open(..., options);
```

I just went through [`open`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man2/open.2.html), the system call that I think actually does the opening. There's no `O_EXLOCK` listed here, so I presume the constant is not available for that reason. The [FreeBSD variant](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man2/openat.2freebsd.html) of `open` and `openat` lists it, but I don't know what to do with it. According to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12083635) `O_EXLOCK` may not be available in Linux.

Comment: The problem is the contant are not always available :( That constant isnt available to me :( You are awesome at searching man! :)

Comment: @Noitidart have a look at the (disappointing) update.

Comment: Thanks so much man for this info! Basically what Im trying to do is open a file that is locked, and if it throws error then i know its in use. So I was thinking of using the `O_EXLOCK` thing but it was just an idea. Do you have any ideas on how to check if file is locked? :) I know I can do `lsof` but that sends a message and then processes and then i have to read the output, i was thinking a one shot method like: just open, and on fail its obviously locked, it works on windows :(

Comment: @Noitidart I'd say use an equivalent of [`flock`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/flock.2.html), if it exists. Perhaps you should ask this on [so]: How do I lock a file in a platform-independent way in JavaScript?